# Angular radio-buttons out of sync with model

Tags: angular, parent-child, angular-reactive-forms

I'm having an issue where my radio buttons (view) get out of sync with my model (reactive form) when the same label exists in subsequent questions.

I'm creating some kind of survey app which (of course) contains multiple questions, but when 2 subsequent questions contain the same answer labels in different positions, the view gets out of sync when selecting one of them and navigating between the 2 questions. I've created a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-material-starter-omkvvq) to illustrate the issue. (Same [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-material-starter-jnbscw) without Material)

Reproduction steps wrong selection:

1. Select the second option for question 1 ('MRX').
2. Click the 'Next' button (answer gets stored in model).
3. Select the second option again for question 2 ('Ibanez').
4. Click the 'Previous' button  (answer gets stored in model).
5. Click the 'Next' button again.
6. Now you can see that the view is out of sync with the model (the model is also printed on screen).

Reproduction steps double selection:

1. Select the first option for question 1 ('Ibanez').
2. Click the 'Next' button (answer gets stored in model).
3. Select the second option for question 2 ('Inbanez').
4. Click the 'Previous' button  (answer gets stored in model).
5. Now you can see that 2 options are selected (first and second).

For more information on the app I've added a description in the parent component (survey-parent.component.html) of the stackblitz.

I'm not sure if this is a bug in Angular or that I am doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

How about setting [checked] attribute based on the given answer?

```
    <mat-radio-group formControlName="answer">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let questionAnswer of surveyQuestion.answers; let i = index">
      <mat-radio-button [checked]="isSet(i+1)" color="primary" [value]="i+1">{{questionAnswer}}</mat-radio-button>
      <br /><br />
    </ng-container>
  </mat-radio-group>
```

And in the ts-file:

```
  isSet(i: number){
     return i ===this.surveyQuestion.givenAnswer;
  }
```

I've updated the snippet:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-material-starter-fbs7gk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsurvey-child%2Fsurvey-child.component.ts

Comment: After some extra testing with your solution I found a second issue (see updated question above) which is not solved by your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to fix it in your code, and if i rewrite your survey and it still does not work. It think it is a bug in Angular Material and you can report it here https://github.com/angular/components.

Maybey a workarround for now is  to print all questions and hide all all except the one you wan't to display? In this stackblitz i made a start to display them all, but i have not finished the logic to hide the questions.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-material-starter-2xx7ce

Comment: I don't think it's a bug in Angular Material, because I have added the same project in another Stackblitz in which I stripped all Material parts and it's still showing the issue. It could be an Angular bug though.
I don't want to print all questions at once on the screen and hide them with *ngIfs because we also support multiple choice picture questions and the questions came from a backend server. So it could be a big performance hit if all those pictures need to be transferred to the client in a single request.